# POST method not inserting into users array

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Im trying to figure out why my post Method won't insert the user made in the register form into my user array, and no array is logged in node. When the register button is clicked, the site is also not redirecting to the /login page. Im not looking for the exact solution maybe just a tip to help me on the right path. 
(all libraries is required)

The POST method im using

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
// helps finding specifik path
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000


// users array 
const users = [];

app.use(express.static('views'))

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("App is listening on port 3000")
});

// VIGTIGT: tilader at vi kan hente data fra forms via "Name" tagget i formen!
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// req router fra .auth/user_auth

// Routing: We are mapping to a special respond, and responds a HTML filer
app.get('/contact',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./html/contact.html'))
})
app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./html/login.html'))
})
app.get('/register',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./html/register.html'))
})
app.get('/home',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./html/home.html'))
})
app.get('/portfolio',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./html/portfolio.html'))
})
app.get('/adminpage', (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./html/adminpage.html'))
})

// post metoder fra form



app.post('/register', async (req, res)=>{
    try{
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
users.push({
    id: Date.now().toString(),
    name: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword
})
res.redirect('/login')
    } catch{
res.redirect('/register')
    }
console.log(users)
})


form im using 
<form>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
      <hr>
      <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" required>

      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

      <hr>
      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
      <button href="/login" type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
    </div>  
    <div class="container signin">
      <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Sign in</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: are you able to print req.body?

Comment: I did a console.log(req.body);  and I got "Req is not defined"

Comment: share full code

Comment: edit in OP, if that helps

Comment: firstly change your HTML form, send data thru formaction and method post

Comment: All your routes could be rewritten in one line : `app.get('/:page', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, \`./html/${req.params.page}.html\`)))`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to specify a `method` and an `action` to determine where the data is being sent to:

`<form action="/register" method="POST">
</form>`

Secondly, you are not parsing the incoming data when it is received by your server. The `req.body`syntax implies that the data is received as an object/JSON, but I don't see anything in your code that indicates you are doing this.

You can use one of a number of packages to do this for you, and Express has built-in middleware for this purpose. I'd recommend the `body-parser` package.

`const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Worth adding a temporary `console.log(req.body)` to your function too just to check form data is being received as intended.